# Condition of differentiablity of funtion of several variable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I know that function $f$ is differentiable from the open set $E \subseteq \mathbb R^n \ \ into  \ \ \mathbb R^m$ and x $\in $ E if there exxist a linear transformation  $A$ of $\mathbb R^n$ into $\mathbb R^m$ such that

$$ lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{|f(x+h) - f(x) - Ah|}{|h|} = 0$$

and $f(x)$ can be represent as $f(x)$ = $\sum_{i=1}^m f_i(x) u_i$, where $f_i$ are the components of $f$, i.e $f_i : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ .

> > we have result that if $f$ is differentiable , then the partial derivative $D_jf_i$ exist and $A =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
> > D_1f_1(x) & ..... & D_nf_1(x) \\
> > ............ & ............. & ............. \\
> > D_1f_m(x) & ...... & D_nf_m(x) \end{array} \right)$

Is converse part of the result is true ? if not true ,how to check function is differentiable.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existence of partial derivatives at a point doesn't even guarantee continuity! Consider the function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ defined by
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}, & (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\
0, & (x,y)=(0,0).
\end{cases}
$$
The partial derivative with respect to $x$ at $(0,0)$ is
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} = 0.
$$
You can similarly compute that the partial derivative with respect to $y$ at $(0,0)$ is $0$. On the other hand, the function $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$ because, for example,
$$
\lim_{t\to0}f(t,t)=\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

No, it is well-know that the existence of the partial derivatives is not enough to guarantee differentiability. You need more, and a sufficient condition is the *continuity* of the partial derivatives.

In general, you must use the definition and prove directly that the limit you wrote is zero.